# Any way to intercept a file save and lower the amount of data written?

Tags: macos, filesystems, compression

I'm currently using a program that saves its data to an SD card connected to my Macbook.  This issue is the program writes about ~500MB of data each and every time it saves so it's pretty slow and I'm looking into ways to speed up the process or reduce the amount of data it writes.

I had the idea in my head that I could using something like fswatch to monitor what files are changing and gzip them, but that wouldn't fix the issue because fswatch only reports events after they've happened, not before, so I would just be adding more writes.  Also, I'd have to decompress everything for the program to read the files again.  I'm not sure if OSX Sierra supports some kind of transparent, file system based compression.

Maybe there are other ideas?

Comment: you are probably barking up the wrong tree in terms of intercepting disk writes as they occur. The System API, the Kernel and the disk drivers are all system-space entities, so that kind of interaction is very low level, making it both difficult and dangerous.

Comment: @FrankThomas Another idea I had was using a FUSE filesystem that supports on-the-fly compression and decompression but I wouldn't know where to even start there.